# Customizing Symfony form label based on targeted field type

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony-2.4

I am trying to customize Symfony form label to add an asterisk(*) for all required fields through this [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels). But my asterisk `<span` has to be inside the `<label` tag so I had to customize `form_label` block as described here. So far is good, but the customization also being applied to each item(label) of checkbox/radio fields. where it looks odd.

Any idea, how could I filter it in label customized block to format only for parent labels.

Here is my overridden code :

```
{% block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) -%}
        {% if not compound -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
            {{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
            {% if required %} <span class="required" title="This field is required">*</span> {% endif %}
        </label>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock form_label %}
```

**In brief, I want a variable inside this block to identify the field type this label is targeting to.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I resolved this with some tweak from the variable available in this overridden block. 
Below is my overridden code for condition

```
    {% if (required) and ( form.vars.checked is not defined ) %}
        <span class="validation-error-star" title="This field is required">*</span>
    {% endif %}
```

Instead of only required variable as condition, I further added another condition if there is any checked attribute defined for this field; which normally a radio/checkbox field type has.

This helped me to differentiate the field type inside a label overridden block. hope this helps somebody. :)